# Why wave functions and not sums of vectors?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space

What are the benefits of representing quantum-mechanical states with wave functions rather than with sums of vectors?

Answer (score 2):

Wavefunctions are solutions to a differential equations, which usually makes them a function.

They are also vectors: just vectors in a space of functions.  They are vectors in the sense they can be added together, multiplied by (complex) numbers and one can even talk about orthogonal wavefunctions.  Indeed, the steady state solutions of the time-independent Schr$\ddot{\hbox{o}}$dinger equations functions as elementary basis vectors in this space of functions.